# Strings Not Converting to Float as Expected

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm facing a problem in converting `str` to `float`. I do like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int) but this time it's not working because I have numbers in this format:

```
5.50000e+000 5.50000e+001 5.50000e+002 5.50000e+003
```

If I change the format (for example using `5.5 55 550 5500`) it works fine. The Traceback states only:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phresREADER.py", line 27, in <module>
    tra = float(stri)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

What can I do? Is there a specific command?

my code is:

```
my_line = f.readline() 
avg_energySTR = [str(i) for i in my_line.split(' ')]
for stri in avg_energySTR:
        tra = float(stri)
```

when I print avg_energySTR I get

['5.50000e+000', '5.50000e+001', '5.50000e+002', '5.50000e+003', '\n']

THE ANSWER IS IN THE KOJIRO'S COMMENT

Comment: `float("5.50000e+000")` works for me.

Comment: works for me also, python 2.7, can you show us your output / trace back?

Comment: Just tested in console on Python2.7 and Python3.3 `float('5.50000e+000')` outputs `5.5`, `float(5.50000e+000)` outputs `5.5`, even just typing in `5.50000e+000` outputs `5.5`

Comment: what is inside `avg_energySTR`?, you probably have a problem in the for statement.

Comment: Eh it's strange, but here it doesn't work!

Comment: same right result,could you show more about this?

Comment: what do you want to see?

Comment: @user3254025 the content of `avg_energySTR`, that's what we need to see

Comment: @user3254025 add `print(avg_energySTR)` before the `for` loop and post what you get.

Comment: Do `split()` with no arguments: perhaps your whitespace is not just the `' '` character.

Comment: yep, @kojiro was right, you matched a `\n` newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `'\n'` at one of the list cells.

So when the iteration is trying to convert `'\n'` to float it raise an `ValueError`

Try this code:

```
avg_energySTR = "5.50000e+000 5.50000e+001 5.50000e+002 5.50000e+003"
avg_energySTR = [str(i) for i in avg_energySTR.split()]
avg_energy = []
for stri in avg_energySTR:
        tra = float(stri)
        avg_energy.append(tra)
print (avg_energy)
```

You can also just split at the for itself:

```
avg_energySTR = "5.50000e+000 5.50000e+001 5.50000e+002 5.50000e+003 \n"
avg_energy = []
for stri in avg_energySTR.split():
       .......
```

Comment: Or just `avg_energy = [float(stri) for stri in avg_energySTR.split()]`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
avg_energySTR = [str(i) for i in my_line.split(' ')]
```

To:

```
avg_energySTR = my_line.split()
```

From the comments, it appears that you have extra whitespace at the end of the line. If you use the default split algorithm (by passing no arguments, or by passing `None`), then trailing whitespace will be ignored.